# Repaire Message in Office 2013 but open fine in other versions

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentationml

I've generated a presentation using OpenXML SDK 2.0 which opens fine in Office 2007 or 2010 but gives Repaire message in Office 2013, OpenXML SDK Productivity tool validation functionality didn't provide much help. Can anyone please tell me what's the problem? The presentation can be downloaded from:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C4B0274BA6703509!300

Comment: Try hitting repair, and do a textual diff on all the files inside the .docx to see what changed.

Comment: I see lots of id changes but why in Office 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue, it turns out that the merging code given in this article needs a revisit as far as Office 2013 is concerned:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee361883(v=office.12).aspx

In case anyone else having the same problem, I've used OpenXML Power tools and PresentationBuilder in particular to resolve this issue:

http://powertools.codeplex.com/